# How to share users data between multiple subdomains in joomla?

Tags: joomla, jomsocial

Today I came across following situation

I have a joomla and jomsocial site **(http://www.mydomain.com)** hosted on server. It has several custom (third party) components installed on it.

Now I want to upgrade this site to latest version of joomla and jomsocial. Hurdle is some third party components are not yet compatible with the latest version.

So I am planning to host these components on subdomain **(http://mycomponent.mydomain.com)**

Now the conditions I have are

- User must be same for both the site.
- If user logs in to main site and then opens subdomain (using link provided on main site), he should be logged in to subdomain and vice versa **(i.e. Single Sign On)**
- Database can be different for both sites.

I am not getting a idea, how to proceed with this. I am thinking about using web services to communicate with main site.

Any suggestions or links to guide will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Host the components on a subdomain? Bad idea. What version of Joomla are you currently using? If 1.5, are the 3rd party extensions you're using compatible with Joomla 2.5? If so, I would suggest upgrading to 2.5 for the time being.

Comment: @Lodder I amusing Joomla version 2.5 and planning to upgrade to latest version. And 3rd party components are not compatible with latest version. Why hosting the components on a subdomain is bad idea?

Comment: @Amol: you're just making your architecture a maintenance nightmare: eventually the 3rd party components will be migrated to Joomla 3, and most likely the effort of getting SSO and SEF run smoothly (you don't want to lose your urls I guess) will be more than migrating the components yourself

Answer (score 0):

There are Extension on JED which provide Single Sign On functionality to joomla. If they work may depend on your versions of Joomla...